# How to show $\|x-y\|_2^2 \leq \|x\|_2^2+2|x^Ty|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, trace, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

How can I show the following 
$$\|x-y\|_2^2 \leq \|x\|_2^2+2|x^Ty|$$

The above has been used by the authors of the following paper on page 8, in first line
[Online Principal Component Analysis](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/papers/opca.pdf).

Also, I think using the above for $M , N \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$ the following is true.
$$\|M-N\|_F^2 \leq \|M\|_F^2+2|\text{tr}(M^TN)|$$
where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is Frobenius norm.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be true. take x, y such that $x^{T}y=0$

Comment: @ zimbra314: Could you take a look at the paper that I have cited. It is a well-known paper.

Comment: Evenif the inequality was true (which it is not),  equation 8 on page 7 will change its inequality sign so equation 8 is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have hard time to prove:

$$\|x-y\|_2^2 \leq \|x\|_2^2+2|x^Ty|$$

Take $x = 0$ and $y \neq 0$, you get:

$$\|y\|_2^2 \le 0$$

which is unlikely.

Comment: But in the following paper which is a well-known paper on page 8, in first line, the author claims this http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/papers/opca.pdf. Maybe, for $x=0$ $y$ has to be zero.

Comment: There is probably a typo in the paper. Take $n = 2$, $x=(0.1,0.0)$ and $y=(0,1)$. The inequality clearly doesn't hold.

Comment: But it uses at equation (8), could you take a look, I have spent a day on that to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry. I won't spend time on it. The inequality is clearly wrong. Just have a look at the counterexample I provided in the comment above. And make the computation ==> $0.1^2 + 1^2 \nleq 0.1^2$.